# Hibernate 4.1 Errror: Could not create DynamicParameterizedType for type: org.hibernate.type.EnumType

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I am trying to upgrade my project from hibernate 3.6 to 4.1.6, I think I have got all the jars in the right place, ... etc but now I have this exception below googling has not yielded an answer. My code runs fine on Hibernate 3.6 and I am not sure if this is a problem with my mappings or something else.  I am configuring hibernate 4.1 with Spring 3.1.2 using the JPA approach.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not create DynamicParameterizedType for type: org.hibernate.type.EnumType
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createParameterImpl(SimpleValue.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:304)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:294)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:238)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:469)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1294)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1738)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
        ... 55 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: char
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createParameterImpl(SimpleValue.java:389)
        ... 64 more
```

**Update:** I have put break points in the hibernate code where that exception is caught and have found the mapping that it does not like, here is it below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company_addresses")
public class CompanyAddress extends TimeStampedPersistableObject
{
public enum AddressType
{
    PUBLIC('p'), SHAREHOLDER('s');

    private final char typeCode;

    AddressType(char typeCode)
    {
        this.typeCode = typeCode;
    }

    public static AddressType parse(char c)
    {
        for (AddressType addressType : AddressType.values())
        {
            if (addressType.value() == c)
            {
                return addressType;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public char value()
    {
        return typeCode;
    }
}

@Column(name = "address_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private char type;
```

Comment: Is there any BeanCreationException or something like that?

Comment: nope no noBeanCreationException, the two exception above the bottom of the stack trace

Comment: Could you, please, post a class where you use `org.hibernate.type.EnumType`?

Comment: Your mapped classes would be somewhat useful here.

Comment: I have turned on full tracing, I can't geven get hibernate to print out what mapping is causing problems. I have more than 50 entities and I can't figure out which one is causing the problem.

Comment: see updates, I have managed to locate the mapping it does not like which works perfectly fine with Hibernate 3.6.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I had an extra @Enumerated which hibernate 3.6 was ignoring which was confusing to hibernate 4.1

```
@Column(name = "address_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private char type;
```

I had forgotten @Enumerated on this field which has a char type but the setters and getter using a proper Enum. Removing @Enumerated fixed the problem, which was a bug in my mapping.

Hibernate 4.1 failed to indicated the name of the table and the name of the column which made it a bit hard to figure out which mapping was causing the problem.